# Java: Read from txt file and store each word only once in array + sorting

Tags: java

I am having a problem with my program. What i am supposed to do is:

1. find all words from some txt files
2. store each word in array **only once**
3. Then sort alphabetically

I dont know how to ensure that each word won't appear twice(or more) in my array.
For example, a sentence from one of my files: My cat is huge and my dog is lazy.
I want the words "my" and "is" to appear only once in my array, not twice.

As for the sorting, is there anything that i can use from Java ? I don't know.

Any help is appreciated!

Here is what i have done so far:

```
try {
    File dir = new File("path of folder that contains my files")

    for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));
        String line = null;
        while((line = br.readLine())!= null) {
            String [] tokens = line.split(",\\s+|\\s*\\\"\\s*|\\s+|\\.\\s*|\\s*\\:\\s*");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the words into a `SortedSet<String>` instead of an array; then call `set.toArray(new String[0])` at the end.

Comment: `SortedSet` is an interface.

Comment: So? You just use a class which implements it, e.g. `TreeSet<String>`.

Comment: What will that set.toArray(new String[0]) do?

Comment: @Chris [Always check the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray(T[]))

Comment: Yeah ehm.. i've read it but still i dont think i fully understood it...

Comment: "Returns an array containing all of the elements in this set" is all you need to read.

Comment: Aha. I will carefully implement it and see if it fits me :) Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ifI guess you are looking for a code something like this.

```
try {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    File dir = new File("path of folder that contains my files")

    for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));
        String line = null;
        while((line = br.readLine())!= null) {
            String [] tokens = line.split(",\\s+|\\s*\\\"\\s*|\\s+|\\.\\s*|\\s*\\:\\s*");
            for(int i=0; i<tokens.length(); i++)
            {  //Adding non-duplicates to arraylist
               if (!list.contains(tokens[i])  
               {
                   list.add(tokens[i]);
               }
            }
        }
        Collections.Sort(list);
    }
}
catch(Exception ex){}
```

Do not forget: `import java.util.*;` at the beginning of your code to use Collections.Sort();

EDIT

Even though contains is a built-in method you can directly use with ArrayLists, this is how such a method works in fact (just in case if you are curious):

```
public static boolean ifContains(ArrayList<String> list, String name) {
    for (String item : list) {
        if (item.getName().equals(name)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

then to call it:

```
ifContains(list, tokens[i]))
```

Comment: What's the `ifContains` method for?

Comment: No, really, what's it for? What's wrong with `list.contains(tokens[i])`? And why not just use a `Set`?

Comment: Nothing I think, but seems like he is beginner so it would be beneficial for him to see how contains working in real :)

Comment: It's bad practice to show beginners things like that, because they may not know that a built-in method exists. Show the Right Way™ to implement the code (and that would be to use a `Set` of some flavour, btw).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution Eray!! Didnt know that there was a built in method for sorting or that built in method " contains"!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the modified code to have sorted unique words:

```
try {
        TreeSet<String> uniqueSortedWords = new TreeSet<String>();
        File dir = new File(
                "words.txt");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(dir)));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] tokens = line
                    .split(",\\s+|\\s*\\\"\\s*|\\s+|\\.\\s*|\\s*\\:\\s*");
            for(String token: tokens) {
                uniqueSortedWords.add(token);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(uniqueSortedWords);
        //call uniqueSortedWords.toArray() to have output in an array
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of HashSet and TreeSet

1. **Hashset**:hashset allows null object.
2. **TreeSet**:treeset will not allow null object,treeset elements are sorted in ascending order by default.
3. **Both HashSet and TreeSet** does not hold duplicate elements.

   ```
   try {
       Set<String> list = new HashSet<>();
       File f = new File("data.txt");

       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));
       String line = null;
       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

           String[] tokens = line.split(",\\s+|\\s*\\\"\\s*|\\s+|\\.\\s*|\\s*\\:\\s*");// other alternative:line.split("[,;-!]")

           for (String token : tokens) {
               list.add(token);
           }
       }
       // Add the list to treeSet;Elements in treeSet are sorted
       // Note: words must have the same case either lowercase or uppercase
       // for sorting to work correctly
       TreeSet<String> sortedSet = new TreeSet<>();
       sortedSet.addAll(list);

       Iterator<String> ite = sortedSet.iterator();
       while (ite.hasNext()) {
           System.out.println(ite.next());
       }

   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```